# Annual Conversion: How-T0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd like to know how to convert prices -- $\$20$ per month is how much in one year? For example: "Tim pays $\$20$ a month for his cell phone bill. How much will he pay in one year?"

Comment: How many months are there in one year? They are not that many, maybe making a table of how much he has paid until every month will give you the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In science classes at least, there's a concept called dimensional analysis, which lets you get from one set of units to another set of units.

$$\require{cancel} \frac{\$20}{1\text{ month}}=\frac{\$20}{1\cancel{\text{ month}}}\times \frac{12\cancel{\text{ months}}}{1\text{ year}}=\frac{\$20\times12}{1\text{ year}}=\frac{\$240}{1\text{ year}}$$

What I did is that we had months, but we wanted years, so I related months and years together. You can see that the 'months' units cancel each other out.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my "canceling". Anywhere in the post, you can simply add `\require{cancel}`. From then on, anywhere in the post, simply use `\cancel{<item to cancel>}`. If you'd want "rollback," to your original post, please feel free to do so. BTW: +1

Comment: @amWhy Hey that was really useful. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I learned it only by checking the edit history when someone else used it!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the the amount of change per unit(change in money, per month) by total units (12 months)